# Match file names and replace with new name

Tags: python, bash, shell, python-2.7, notepad++

I have two rather large .txt files with similar ID tags.  What I need to do is take the ID tag from one file, match it in the other and replace the ID with the name from the first file. I need to have this done for 1000+ tags.  The key is to exactly match part of the ID tag name from the first file and replace it.

- There is a unique ID tag per line and there is always a exact match between the two files  (for positions [6-16] = "10737.G1C22"); matches are scattered, so line 1 from File1.txt may match with line 504 in File2.txt
- The order of the lines in both files cannot be sorted and must be maintained

For example:

```
File1.txt = 
TYPE1_10737.G1C22 ---------
...

File2.txt = 
10737.G1C22 ----------
```

I need the name from File1.txt, specifically "10737.G1C22" to find its exact match in File2.txt and replace it to "TYPE1_10737.G1C22".

The edit then would look like this where now the names in File2.txt were changed according to matches from File1.txt:

```
 File2.txt = 
 TYPE1_10737.G1C22 ---------
 ...
```

I have tried a few sed functions, but got stuck. It is important that only the first 6 characters of the name get changed once a exact match is found and not anything else. There are over 1000+ ID tags that need to be matched and changed.

I am thinking of code that tells it to match exactly positions [6-16] and replace it with [0-16] from File1.txt.

Any help is much appreciated. Is this even possible? I am open for alternative suggestions as well. Thank you.

Comment: One ID per line, always at beginning of line in each file?  Is there at most one match in file1 for each file2 ID?

Comment: Yes. One ID per line and yes there is at least one match between the files. Thank you!

Comment: One way would be to generate a dictionary (I see your python tag) from file1 where the key is the match to be found in file2 and the dictionary value would be the full name.  Then read file2, lookup in dictionary, and rewrite line to a new file.

Comment: Is order of lines in file2 important? i.e. can it and file1 be sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution in python:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
LINES_PER_CYCLE = 1000

with open('output.txt', 'wb') as output, open('test_2.txt', 'rb') as fin:
    fin_line = ''

    # Loop until fin reaches EOF.
    while True:
        cache = OrderedDict()

        # Fill the cache with up to LINES_PER_CYCLE entries.
        for _ in xrange(LINES_PER_CYCLE):
            fin_line = fin.readline()
            if not fin_line:
                break

            key, rest = fin_line.strip().split(' ', 1)
            cache[key] = ['', rest]

        # Loop over the file_1.txt to find tags with given id.    
        with open('test_1.txt', 'rb') as fout:
            for line in fout:
                tag, _ = line.split(' ', 1)
                _, idx = tag.rsplit('_', 1)
                if idx in cache:
                    cache[idx][0] = tag

        # Write matched lines to the output file, in the same order
        # as the lines were inserted into the cache.
        for _, (tag, rest) in cache.iteritems():
            output.write('{} {}\n'.format(tag, rest))

        # If fin has reached EOF, break.    
        if not fin_line:
            break
```

What it does is reading up to `LINES_PER_CYCLE` entries from the `file_2.txt`, finding matching entries in `file_1.txt` and writing to the output. As a result of limited memory (for cache), `file_1.txt` is searched through multiple times.

This assumes that the tag/id part is separated by whitespace from the `-------`, and that the tag and id are separated by an underscore from themselves, ie. 'tag_idx blah blah'.

Answer (score 1):

### Bash and `ed` solution

- Step 1. Create `File1.txt` and `File2.txt` that more or less look like yours to experiment and have some fun (with 1000 lines). Use this script (in a scratch directory):

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  declare -A table

  while ((${#table[@]}!=1000)); do
      key=$(mktemp -u XXXXXXXXXX)
      key=${key:0:5}.${key:5}
      table[${key^^}]=1
  done

  {
      for key in "${!table[@]}"; do
          echo "TYPE1_$key some junk here" >&3
          echo "$key some more junk here"
      done | shuf > File2.txt
  } 3> File1.txt
  ```
- Step 2. Use `ed`, the standard editor to do the substitution, wrapped in this script:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  ed -s File2.txt < <(
     while read l _; do
        p=${l:6}
        p=${p//./\\.}
        echo "%s/^$p/$l/"
     done < File1.txt
     echo wq
  )
  ```

  This assumes that you only have the alphanumerical characters, the underscore `_` and the period `.`. If you have other characters, modify appropriately (so as not to clash with regexps).
- Step 3. Check and enjoy:

  ```
  vimdiff <(sort File1.txt) <(sort File2.txt)
  ```

Done.

**Note.** As `ed` is a genuine editor, the substitutions are done in place. `File2.txt` is really *edited*.

---

Hey, wait I might have overlooked your requirement with the 16 characters... I used the fact that there's a space after your pattern. If my solution is not good regarding this point, please let me know, I'll modify it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Python-based solution would be straightforward, note however, that this can't be done in-place, you have to store result to some new location, for example [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html).

If your files aren't unreasonably big, i.e. you can construct mapping in memory, it is straight-forward (assuming 1) name is separated from id with underscore, 2) id is separated from text with space, as in example 3) each line contains both id and name 4) only one name per id exists in file1):

```
file1 = ('TYPE1_10737.G1C22 ---------', )
file2 = ('10737.G1C22 +++++++++++', )
id_name_gen = (l.split(' ', 1)[0] for l in file1)
id2name_mapping = {line.split('_', 1)[1]: line for line in id_name_gen}
```

Replace can be done easily, once you have a mapping (keep string unchanged if no match found):

```
id_rest_gen = (l.split(' ', 1) for l in file2)
file2updated_gen = ('{} {}'.format(id2name_mapping.get(id, id), rest) for id, rest in file2)

>>> list(file2updated_gen)
['TYPE1_10737.G1C22 +++++++++++']
```

You just have to store resulting generator to file.

Answer (score 1):

I would load the first file into a dict, then process the second file for matching keys, outputting any changes to a 3rd file:

```
import re

# Pattern to match in File1
pattern1 = "(\w+)_(\d+\.\w+)\s+.*$"

# Pattern to match in File2
pattern2 = "(\d+\.\w+)\s+.*$"

# Load the 'master' file into a dict,
# with the number as key and 'type' as value.
file1_dict = dict()
with open("File1.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        m = re.match(pattern1, line)
        if m:
            file1_dict[m.group(2)] = m.group(1)

# Open a new output file to replace File2.txt
with open("File3.txt", "w") as fnew:
    # As you process each line in File2.txt,
    # find matching entry in above File1 list.
    # Either write the old unmatched value or new
    # matching, changed value to File3.txt
    with open("File2.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            is_found = False
            m = re.match(pattern2, line)
            if m:
                if m.group(1) in file1_dict:
                    is_found = True
                    fnew.write("{0}_{1}".format(file1_dict[m.group(1)], line))
            if not is_found:
                fnew.write(line)

# Then just overwrite File2.txt with new File3.txt contents.

# Original File1.txt
TYPE1_10737.G1C22 ---------
TYPE1_10738.G1C22 ---------
TYPE1_10739.G1C22 ---------
TYPE1_10740.G1C22 ---------
TYPE1_10741.G1C22 ---------
TYPE1_10742.G1C22 ---------
TYPE1_10799.G1C22 ---------

# Original File2.txt
10737.G1C22 ---------
10738.G1C22 ---------
10739.G1C22 ---------
10740.G1C22 ---------
10788.G1C22 ---------
10741.G1C22 ---------
10742.G1C22 ---------

# Results of new File3.txt
TYPE1_10737.G1C22 ---------
TYPE1_10738.G1C22 ---------
TYPE1_10739.G1C22 ---------
TYPE1_10740.G1C22 ---------
10788.G1C22 ---------
TYPE1_10741.G1C22 ---------
TYPE1_10742.G1C22 ---------
```